# Skype4Py cannot determine window state

Tags: python, macos, skype4py

I am on Mac OSX (10.8.2) and am trying to use Skype4py to send messages in response to incoming messages only if the Skype window is Minimized.

The code that I have set up is basically as follows:

```
s = Skype4Py.Skype()
c = s.Client
if not c.IsRunning:
    c.Start()
s.FriendlyName = "AR"
s.Attach()
```

Ok... that is pretty basic and makes complete sense, right? My problem is that I am trying to check and see if the window is closed... and although http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.client.Client-class.html list `IsRunning` and `WindowState` in the same place... no matter how format it or try to referance it, I cannot get any reference to `c.WindowState` to work.

They all produce an `Skype4Py.errors.SkypeError: [Errno 7] GET: invalid WHAT`... Which is an error code completely foreign to me.

Comment: Are you sure you can change any properties before you have attached the client? Put on debug logging and get trace of Skype API protocol dump so you see what causes invalid GET and there is more information to debug the issue. Skype API reference is here https://developer.skype.com/desktop-api-reference

Comment: After running s.Attach() is where I try to put references to c.WindowState. Just to test it, I normally am just trying to print it "print c.WindowState" or set it to a variable. I have already tested the code that is written above, and it works, including starting te client if the client isn't already started. I also have other code afterwards that sends messages to people and it words correctly as long as I comment out all references to c.WindowState. The link you sent has coding examples and information for Skype Desktop API.. Since I'm using Skype4Py, the coding examples seem useless.

Comment: Skype4Py internally uses Skype desktop API. So your error codes and situations should be described in that documentation. Please try to increase logging level to further debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't speak english! :)

Window state print out: `print 'client: ' + str(skype.Client.WindowState)`

```
 Window state
    wndUnknown = 'UNKNOWN'
    wndNormal = 'NORMAL'
    wndMinimized = 'MINIMIZED'
    wndMaximized = 'MAXIMIZED'
    wndHidden = 'HIDDEN'
```

usage:

```
s = Skype4Py.Skype()
c = s.Client
if not c.IsRunning:
    c.Start()
if (c.WindowState == Skype4Py.wndUnknown) | (c.WindowState == Skype4Py.wndHidden):
    # kill the skype with shell (killall -9 skype)
    c.Start()
s.FriendlyName = "AR"
s.Attach()
```